# Likelihood function estimating two different means

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I completely understand how to find the likelihood functions of simple pdfs. However, how would you attempt to find the likelihood function of a pdf with a negative exponential function with two different means, where the overall mean is just the two means added together???

The method to do this would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are describing [mixture model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model). There are a lot of ways of estimating these types of models.